# Excel Data Validation (with or without vba)

Tags: validation

I have a column of cells eg "column C" whereby I would like to input a data validation.

I would like to restrict users to key in either "Done", "NA" or "any dates eg 01/10/2016, 31/03/2013 etc"

How do I create the above data validation? I am alright with using either Excel's "Data validation" function or VBA.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: For each cell in column C, I would like to restrict users to key in only 3 kinds of data.  1) is the the word "Done". 2) is the word "NA". 3) Any dates eg 01/02/2015. If users key in any other data eg "hello", it will be flagged out as an error.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple bit of code here you could make to do whatever, highlight the cell or something, this just sets it back to blank. I would also desensitize them to caps and add some other options like "n/a"

```
Private sub worksheet_change(byval target as range)
   If Target.Value <> "Done" And Target.Value <> "NA" And Not IsDate(Target.Value) Then
      MsgBox ("incorrect entry, enter only blah or blah...")
      Target.Value = ""
   End If
End Sub
```